# How to report an additional reject from inside Ajax done promise

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise

I am looking for the best way to fix this situation. I need additional checks of the returned Ajax data that could cause my `_loadPanel` promise operation to "fail":

```
_loadPanel(url: string, data?: any) : JQueryPromise<any>
{
    return $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: data ? "POST" : "GET",
            data: data
        }).done(function (html: string, textStatus: string)
        {
             // Some function that exracts required data
             var $panel = extractPanelData(html);
             if (!$panel.length)
             {
                 // How to cause a reject here???
             }
        });
}
```

You can't do this (below) as the promise returned from Ajax is immutable and it just smells wrong anyway:

```
var promise = $.ajax({...}).done(function(...)
{ 
     promise.reject("Data failed promise");
});
```

Is there a simple way of doing this that does not involve adding an extra `$.Deferred()` object or is that the only pattern?

### Attempts:

I have tried the following, so that I could modify a parent `Deferred` object but it will not compile:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var promise = dfd.promise();
promise = promise.then($.ajax(
            {
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                type: data ? "POST" : "GET",
                data: data
            }).done(...));
```

It will to allow me to combine an `Ajax` promise with a `Deferred` promise

`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:Type '(value: {}) => {}' requires a call signature, but type 'JQueryXHR' lacks one.`

Suggestions?

### Something cool:

Not sure how widely known this is, and it does not help this problem (as it also returned an immutable promise), but it appears you can use `$.when` to pass *initial parameters* to the first function

e.g. passing initial parameters to `$.ajax` like this:

```
    $.when({
            url: url,
            type: data? "POST" : "GET",
            data: data
        }).then($.ajax).done(function (html: string, textStatus: string)
```

or separate parameters like this:

```
$.when("Hello!", 22, "There!")
    .then(insertPanel);
```

This can have interesting benefits *if the result is chained to previous promises* as the Ajax call is not longer run immediately, but only after the previous steps complete.

Comment: if you want to reject, `throw` from a `then`.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Are you implying that the exception system is tied to the jQuery promise system?

Comment: the jquery promises should be handling exceptions

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Do you have a reference as I am not finding anything useful (so far). I was not aware they handled exceptions in async operations.

Comment: you could use Q and wrap the jquery promise with it.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: I just want to play nicely with `jQuery promises`. What I am trying to do should not be that hard (just escapes me at the moment) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie for what it's worth - jQuery promises are [severely broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred/23744774#23744774) and are a lot less fun to work with than for example - Bluebird promises, which are a lot moire debuggable.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the _whole point_ of promises is to handle exceptions and returns in asynchronous contexts. However, jQuery are [missing the point of promises](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Thanks for the tips. I will take a look at Bluebird as soon as I sort out my current issue :)

Comment: Any updates on your progress?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thigns here:

- `.then` chains promises and changes their state.
- `.done` does not chain promises, but adds a handler to the *current* promise and returns it.

So:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({...});
p = xhr.then(function(data){
    // fail if check fails
    if(additionalChecksFail) return $.Deferred.reject(Error("Invalid Request").promise(); 
    return data; // otherwise we maintain the same data
});

p.then(function(data){
   // will only run if data validation passed.
});
```

Comment: I though `done` returned the original promise as they do indeed chain (usually to `fail` next).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes, it returns the original promise, it does not chain promises (think of an actual chain for this analogy :)).

Comment: I am confused then why I couldn't do `.then($ajax().done())` which is what my attempt was doing (if you ignore the detail). That should be the same object as `.then($ajax())` which I thought was valid. Is this just a strong typing issue with Typescript?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `$ajax` returns a promise where `.then` accepts a function you can do `.then(function(res){ return $.ajax(..); })` this is like how you pass a callback function instead of invoke it directly.

Comment: I have been using `then` to chain functions that return promises in tests. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s8XmJ/1/ It runs the promises sequentially, chains the results for subsequent `then`s

Comment: Benjamin, those two bullet points could be better phrased. As they stand, they are very misleading.

Comment: Just back from holiday. Will be trying it tomorrow. Thanks for your patience. :)