# jQuery: execute array of functions sequentially (both deferreds and non-deferreds)

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am fairly new to using Promises and have a hard time of wrapping my head around jQuery deferreds.

What I currently have is an array of functions which I execute at a certain point:

```
while (queue.length) {
    (queue.shift())();   
}
```

The problem with this is, that some of those functions are asynchronous, but I need them to run one after another.

So some of the functions in the queue return a deferred (e.g. via jQuery.ajax()) and some are just normal functions. I would like to know if how it would be possible to execute them in order + sequentially (executing the next function only when the previous one has finished).

I thought maybe jQuery.when would be what I am looking for, but I can't figure out how to it exactly, I came only up with this:

```
var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    while (queue.length > 0) {
       deferred.done().then(queue.shift());
    }
```

Comment: if there are async function.. then those functions has to return a promise or need to support a callback mechanism... only then you can do it

Comment: the async functions will return promises, the others won't though

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Very astute, `jQuery.when` *is* what you're looking for. It takes either a promise or a normal non-thenable and returns a promise over that value. However, since you have functions and not values here that isn't really required since this is the behavior of `.then` anyway.

```
var queue = [syncFunction, syncFunc2, returnsPromiseAsync];

var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
while (queue.length > 0) {
   d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brTBt/))

Alternatively, you can reduce;

```
var res = queue.reduce(function(prev,cur){ // chain to res later to hook on done
    return prev.then(cur);
}, $.Deferred().resolve());
```

If you have more code doing things below this, since the functions in the queue may run synchronously or asynchronously (or some synchronous and then we hit an async one), to avoid chaos you may want to ensure that the functions always run asynchronously. You can easily do that by wrapping the `resolve` on the initial `Deferred` in a `setTimeout`:

```
var p = $.Deferred();
var res = queue.reduce(function(prev,cur){ // chain to res later to hook on done
    return prev.then(cur);
}, p);
setTimeout(p.resolve.bind(p), 0);
```

Now the process won't start until the timeout occurs, and any code following this will definitely run before the first function from the queue does. In my view, that's inconsistent with the semantics of jQuery's promises (because [they are inconsistent about sync vs. async callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred)), but you may want the consistency.

If you need to know when the process completes, just use a `.then` handler on `res`:

```
res.then(function() {
    // All functions have now completed
});
```

For those situations, here's a simple wrapper function that does both:

```
function clearQueue(q) {
    var p = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(p.resolve.bind(p), 0);

    return q.reduce(function(prev,cur){ 
        return prev.then(cur);
    }, p);
}
```

Example use ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EHFa/)):

```
clearQueue(queue).then(function() {
    console.log("All done");
});
console.log("This runs before any queued function starts");
```

Comment: Now **that** is beautiful. :-)

Comment: @Roamer-1888: That seems to be true in the current implementation; I don't see it documented, though, do you? But with the way functions get passed around in promise-based code, it does seem like they're unlikely to change it (the implementation)...

Comment: I certainly learned about .resolve's and .reject's "detachability", as they called it, from formal jQuery documentation. I can no longer find the original text but recall that it was an earlier version of the [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) page. However, this feature is at least acknowledged, if not actually documented, in the [Deferred examples](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/) at learn.jQuery.com . Look for phrases such as `.then( defer.resolve, defer.reject )`, `setTimeout( defer.resolve, ...)` and `image.onerror = defer.reject`.