# jQuery promise to simulate synchronous calls of function over array

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

Let' say I need to make a synchronous upload of files. One after another.
I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931115/jquery-execute-array-of-functions-sequentially-both-deferreds-and-non-deferred) topic. And modified the code:

```
var arr = ["file1", "file2", "file3"];

var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
while (arr.length > 0) {
   d = d.then(uploadFile(arr.shift()));
}

function uploadFile(file){
    var d = $.Deferred();    
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Uploading file:"+file); d.resolve(""); },1000);
    return d.promise();
}
```

But i still get them all called asynchronously, but with timeout 1000.

Here is fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shg69k51/3/)

**SOLUTION:**
Big thanx to Felix. Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shg69k51/4/)

Comment: You have to pass a function to `.then`, not a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to `.then`. Currently you are calling `uploadFile` immediately inside the loop and passing a promise to `.then` instead of a function.

You can do the following without having to use a loop:

```
d.then(function next() {
  var promise = uploadFile(arr.shift());
  return arr.length === 0 ? promise : promise.then(next);
});
```

This uses indirect recursion instead of a loop.

Comment: I haven't done much (if any) deferring with jQuery.  Would the following also work? `d.then(function() { uploadFile(arr.shift()) });` if redefining the upload by removing the promise (`function uploadFile(file) { console.log("Uploading file:" + file); }`)?

Comment: Or, I suppose the promise is necessary for the synchronicity

Comment: *"I suppose the promise is necessary for the synchronicity"* Yes. Without that it wouldn't wait for the timeout. Also, if your code was still inside the loop, the loop would never terminate because the `arr.shift()` happens *inside* the callback and thus `arr.length` would never become smaller.

Comment: Reading up on: https://abdulapopoola.com/2014/12/12/the-differences-between-jquery-deferreds-and-the-promisesa-spec/ -- cool stuff.  I think my new interest in life is to take a break from a language and then revisit them to see what I've forgotten or never learned :) tbh, I've been doing less jQuery and more React/ES6-only lately