# ES6 Promise polyfill based on jQuery Deferred

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, polyfills, es6-promise

I recently downloaded a library that uses ES6 Promises. Since I want to deploy to browsers which don't support Promises I also downloaded a [polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise).

Since I've got jQuery included anyway I thought about writing a polyfill for Promise which internally uses jQuery's Deferred.

I wrote this simple polyfill which is enough for my specific use case:

```
    window.Promise = function(cb){
        var promise = $.Deferred();

        cb(promise.resolve, promise.reject);

        return promise.promise();
    };
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't cover the whole specification (thinks like `Promise.all()` are missing).

Before I invest a lot of time into this I'd like to know if it is possible to write a full polyfill for Promise using jQuery's Deferred. Or are there some features which can't be replicated?

Comment: I remember someone saying that jquery's deferred don't stick to the promise specs very well, so it might be better to use something else.

Comment: I heard that too but I seem to remember it was more about how jQuery's functions use promises and not about the Deferred in general. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Personally, I would use the polyfill you already have, and keep jQuery Deferreds/Promises well and truly separate unless you are unavoidably cornered into mixing them.

Comment: @Thomas Could compose piece without utilizing jquery , including implementation for different usages ; a `when` , `done` , `callback` , etc . Perhaps create flow graph of prospective implementation , with documentation of project implementation goals. A brief piece utilizing js without jquery , which includes a `when` and `done` ; `.then` is native promise , chain-able http://stackoverflow.com/a/23587868 . If possible , can describe which processing features which would be provided ?, that `promise` , jquery `deferred` implementation not provide ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> things like `Promise.all()` are missing

`Promise.all` can be more or less replicated by [using `$.when`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572). `Promise.race` can be replicated by creating a deferred whose `resolve`/`reject` methods are attached to all input promises.

> The problem with this is that it doesn't cover the whole specification

No. The parts that are not covered could easily be added. The real problem is that the *existing* parts of the jQuery `Deferred` implement **do not comply** with the specification - see [Problems inherent to jQuery $.Deferred (jQuery 1.x/2.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572)

> Before I invest a lot of time into this I'd like to know if it is possible to write a full polyfill for Promise using jQuery's Deferred. Or are there some features which can't be replicated?

Everything can be replicated, but you'd need to monkeypatch enough in the `Deferred` implementation that you are better of just using one of the existing polyfills. If you really want to create your own, you might base it on a [`jQuery.Callbacks("once memory")`](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/).