# do jQuery promises conform Promises/A+

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have read [this article](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/) which is based on famous [Domenic Denicola's article](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970). The first one says:

> The problem with jQuery’s implementation (**up until version 1.9**) is
>   that it doesn’t respect the second part of the specification, “This
>   function should return a new promise…”, that is “then” doesn’t return
>   a new promise object when executing one of the handlers (either the
>   fullfillment, the rejection or the progress handler).

I have found these bugs corresponding to this problem:

- http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14510
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1722

My question is: what is the current state of this issue? Both are opened, so the work is still in progress. But, using jquery 2, you can chain promises with `.then`. So: is still jQuery.Promises implementation broken? Did anything change since version 1.9?

Comment: I love how you just linked to a github post I commented on earlier today :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** As of jQuery 3.0 the answer is *yes*. jQuery promises are Promises/A+ compatible and can be safely used.

---

jQuery promises do not currently adhere to the Promises/A+ specification and thus [**have some issues**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred) and Domenic's article is still valid.

That said active work is being done and jQuery promises **will finally be Promises/A+ compliant** in the next version. It's still work in progress [here is the relevant pull request](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1996) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1821). The last bit of work on it was two days ago.

Exciting times indeed.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum For this Questions' completion sake, can I be the irritating child in the car back seat and ask "Are we there yet?"