# How to change promise resolve result in chained .then() function

Tags: jquery, promise

Right now, I have a rejected promise chain:

```
dfd = $.Deferred();

dfd
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        return x + 1; // 2
    })
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        return x + 1; // 3
    })
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        log('reject ' + x); // 3
        return x + 1; // 4
    });

dfd.reject(1)
```

I wonder how can I resolve it(steer to success handler) down along the .then chain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By returning a resolved promise at any desired point:

```
dfd
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        return x + 1; // 2
    })
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        return $.Deferred().resolve(x + 1); // switch to success
    })
    .then(function(){}, function(x) {
        log('reject ' + x); // this will never happen now
    });
```

The relevant part of the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) is (emphasis mine)

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to
>   the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return
>   another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) *which will pass
>   its resolved / rejected status and values* to the promise's callbacks.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that a resolved jQuery promise can be generated with `$.when()` or `$.when(value)`, either of which can be returned from an error handler to send a promise chain down the success path.

Comment: Note that starting with the next version of jQuery doing `return x + 1` would also work.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I didn't know that. Is there somewhere I can read more about it?

Comment: @Jon the most recent place I wrote about it with references is [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088034/do-jquery-promises-conform-promises-a/28088881#28088881) but the jQuery issue tracker is a good place to read about it too.