# Why Deferred.fail isn't being called?

Tags: jquery, promise

I've read [this article](http://abdulapopoola.com/2014/12/12/the-differences-between-jquery-deferreds-and-the-promisesa-spec/) about the fact that *jQuery deferreds are not Promise/A+ compliant*

Which leads me to test a code (*which should raise error without propagating to main window and stop running , they suggested similar code , but I wanted to try and make it simplier - hence my question*):

```
var def = new jQuery.Deferred();
var bar = def.then(function (rslv) {

 try {
    throw Error('Exception!');
 }
 catch (e) {

    def.reject();
 }

 return def.promise();
});

bar.fail(function (val) { //why doesn't this line run ?
 console.log('Exception thrown and handled');
});
def.resolve();

console.log(1)
```

**Question:**

`def.then(...)` returns a promise which is kept in `bar`

`bar` - when failed - should run :

```
  bar.fail(function (val) {
     console.log('Exception thrown and handled');
    });
```

But it is not running.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can only resolve/reject a deferred once.

Comment: @A.Wolff f* I forgot about that. thanks

Comment: You are resolving `def` once... then is rejecting it... a promise can be resolved/rejectd only once

Comment: Now I understand why they used 2 deferreds

Comment: You could alternatively use Signals, e.g: http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/

Comment: In jQuery 3.0 the promises are A+ compliant

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred

Comment: @A.Wolff consider posting the "resolve/reject once" (it's called resolve, and it's actually fulfill/reject) as an answer it sounds right. As for signals - consider looking at FRP libraries like RxJS :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You are the promise expert here. I'm quite sure you could made a great answer/explaination :)

Comment: I'd much rather having more people involved in the Promise tag than answer more questions :) Go right ahead.

Comment: @benjamin what do you mean by FRP ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir functional reactive programming, ping me on facebook for slides I'm giving at ng-conf-il next week on the topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redefining `bar` within initial `bar = def.then(success, error)` of resolved `def` . At  `catch` set `bar` as new `jQuery.Deferred()`, calling `reject` with `e` as parameter , returning "new" `bar.promise()` , which should call `error` at `bar.then(success, error)` ; and allow `bar` to be "chained" to jQuery promise methods

```js
var def = new jQuery.Deferred();

var success = function success(data) {
  console.log("success", data)
};

var error = function error(val) { //why doesn't this line run ?
 console.log('Exception thrown and handled', val, val.message);
};

var bar = def.then(function (rslv) {
 // `success`
 console.log("rslv", rslv);
 try {
    throw Error('Exception!');
 }
 catch (e) {
    // return rejected jQuery promise,
    // having `e` reason
    bar = jQuery.Deferred().reject(e);
    
 };
 // call `error` ,
 // return `bar` jQuery promise `Error('Exception!')`,
 // for "chaining" jQuery promise methods
 return bar.promise()
});

// call `success`, call `error`
bar.then(success, error);

def.resolve("success");

console.log(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```