# Differences between Deferred.then(null,func) and Deferred.fail(func) in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I found out today that `Deferred.then(null,func)` and `Deferred.fail(func)` aren't the same thing in JQuery. In ES6's promise, `Promise.then(null,func)` and `Promise.catch(func)` are the same thing, so I was confused by JQuery's functions.

The only difference I know of is this:

```
$.Deferred().reject().promise()
  .fail(function(){
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log('fail caught error'); // NOT printed
  });

$.Deferred().reject().promise()
  .then(null,function(){
    return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log('then caught error'); //printed
  });
```

Are there any other useful differences?

Comment: It is best to get out of the habit of using any of jQuery's proprietary methods like `.fail()` and `.done()`.  They simply don't do what the standards-based `.then()` does.  I just decided to use only `.then()` with jQuery.  Then, when jQuery does actually finally get more standards-based, I won't have to change much or if I cast any jQuery promises to Bluebird promises, I don't have to change things either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the difference between them is that `.fail()` does return the original promise it was called upon while `.then()` does construct a new promise which might resolve with a different value.

However, due to [jQuery's problematic error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572) you won't notice this unless you return a promise from your callback, like you do in your example. It would be much more of a problem if you had compared `fail` to a standard-adhering `catch` invocation.