# jQuery promise callbacks stop firing after a callback triggers an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given 1-3 below:

1. `var a = $.Deferred()`
2. `a.done(function(){throw Error()});`
3. `a.resolve() // Uncaught error`

Now assume the call stack is cleared.  Then I do the following:

4. `a.done(function(){console.log('Done')})`
5. `a.fail(function(){console.log('Fail')})`
6. `a.then(function(){console.log('Then')})`

And nothing happens.  Why?  Why does the uncaught error in (3) preclude futher callbacks from firing?  Is this by design?

Comment: Bad jQuery promise implementation, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23744774/1414562

Comment: One more reason to use Q.  Thanks