# How will this chain of done()'s, then()'s, and fail()'s on JQuery Deferred's be resolved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Let's say I have this code:

```
promise.done(function (x) {
    // First done()
    console.log(x);
    return 123;
}).fail(function (x){
    // First fail()
    console.log(x);
}).then(function (x){
    // First then()
    console.log(x)
}).fail(function (x){
    // Second fail()
    console.log(x);
}).done(function (x){
    // Second then()
    console.log(x);
});
```

How will this execute? If nothing goes wrong, will the chain of execution be:

```
1. The first done()
2. The first then()
3. The second done()
```

If something goes wrong in the first done, will both the first and second `fail()` be called?

Sorry for the new question, I'm trying to learn how chaining works with promises. Thanks!

Comment: Do execute this and check.. What have you tried which does not work as you expect ?

Comment: Don't use `done` or `fail`. Just always use `then`.

Comment: jQuery [ignores exceptions in handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572), it doesn't catch them like a proper promise library would.

Comment: @Bergi If you use then,  how would you handle failures?

Comment: [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) has a second parameter that you should use: `.then(null, function onReject(err) { … })`