# How to use data from multiple AJAX requests into different functions or create an array of values to be used globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, business-catalyst

I creating my first application using Business Catalyst API to GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests using AJAX, the problem I have is that sometimes I need to grab data from different GET calls to generate new requests and apparently I am a bit lost on how to efficiently do it.

Let's say I have a block of ajax calls getting the API data in JSON format like so:

```
function createOrderStatuses(){
  var access_token = BCAPI.Helper.Site.getAccessToken();
  $.ajax({
      url: "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orderstatuses",
      type: "GET",
      connection: "keep-alive",    
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: APIauthorization,
      success: function (status) {
      console.log(status);
       $.each(status.items, function(items, statuses){
         var statusTemplate = '<ul class="large-12 columns margin-distributed statusClass" id="'+ statuses.id +'"><h4 class="lato-bold">' + statuses.label  + '</h4></ul>';
         var changeSelection = '<select class="orderCurrentStatus"><option selected value="'+statuses.id+'">'+status.label+'</option></select>';
        if (statuses.label !== "EXCHANGE FEE PAID"){
         $("#ordersContainer").append(statusTemplate);
         $("#ordersContainer li span.changeStatus[id="+statuses.id+"]").append(changeSelection);
        }
       });
   }
  });
```

Then I am creating my orders like so:

```
function getOrders(){  
  var dateFrom = appSettings.dateFrom+"T00:00:00";
  var dateTo =  appSettings.dateTo+"T00:00:00";
   var orderData;
   $.ajax({
      url: '/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orders?fields=id,entityId,categoryId,statusTypeId,discountCodeId,paymentMethodTypeId,taxCodeId,giftVoucherId,assignedUserId,name,countryCode,shippingPrice,shippingTaxRate,discountRate,giftVoucherAmount,totalPrice,shippingDescription,shippingAttention,shippingInstructions,quote,invoiced,invoiceNumber,invoiceDate,createDate,lastUpdateDate,destinationAddressIsResidential,isIntermediate,shippingRateKey,status,discountCode,workflow,customer,company,taxCode,assignedUser&skip=0&limit=500&order=-invoiceNumber&where={"createDate":{"$gte":"'+dateFrom+'"},"invoiceDate":{"$lte":"'+dateTo+'"}}',
      type: "GET",
      connection: "keep-alive",    
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: APIauthorization,
      success: function (orders) {
      console.log(orders);
         orderData = orders;
      
       $.each(orders.items, function(order){
        
        var createDate = new Date(order.invoiceDate);
        var orderTemplate = 
             '<li class="f-16 expanded callout medium-collapse mid-gray-bg ordersList"><span class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns ordername"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> <a class="gray" href="https://bestkilts.worldsecuresystems.com/CRM/OrderDetailsv2.aspx?EntityID='+order.entityId+'&EntityType=1001&OrderID='+order.id+'"> '+ order.name+"/"+order.countryCode+'</a></span><span class="large-2 medium-2 small-4 columns date center">'+ createDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (createDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + createDate.getDate()).slice(-2) +'</span><span class="large-1 medium-2 small-4 columns amount center">£'+order.totalPrice+'</span><span class="large-1 medium-1 small-4 columns invoice center">'+order.invoiceNumber+'</span><span class="large-2 medium-2 small-6 columns action center f-12">'+order.lastUpdateDate+'</span><span class="large-2 medium-3 small-6 columns action center changeStatus" id="'+order.statusTypeId+'"></span></li>';   
        if(orders){
         $("#ordersContainer .statusClass[id="+order.statusTypeId+"]").append(orderTemplate);
         var invoicesCounter = $('.ordersList').length;
         $("#ordersCount").text(invoicesCounter);
        }
         return "order";
       });
   }
  });// getOrders retrieve
```

But if I want to get a value/data from `getOrders();`, e.g. `order.id` passed into a new function `getCustomers()` and use to compile the whole thing as one result I can't get about doing it!?

```
function getCustomers(order){
    var orderInfo = getOrders();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orders/'+orderInfo.id+'?fields=status,discountCode,workflow,customer,taxCode', //NEED THE ID FROM ORDERS HERE
            type: "GET",
            connection: "keep-alive",    
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: APIauthorization,
            success: function (customer) {
            console.log(customer);
              var orderCustomer = "" ;
             $.each(customer.items, function(customer){
              orderCustomer = customer;  
            $("#ordersContainer").prepend('<span> class="customer">"'+orderCustomer.name+'"</span>');
                 });
             }
            });// get customer name for order       
}
getCustomers();
```

Conclusion collecting the information from different requests and try to use them in one single result is getting anywhere, I need a solution where I can get all the data from the 3 functions/calls or more if comes to happen! And create an `orderDeployment()` function combining all the data from the 3 into the `ordersContainer`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a jqXHR (jQuery superset of XMLHttpRequest) object which implements the jQuery Promise interface (see [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object for more information).

I don't know if you are familiar with the concept of Promise, but even if jQuery has its own implementation of Promise, the definition [from MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is also valid for jQuery implementation:

> The Promise object is used for asynchronous computations. A Promise
>   represents a value which may be available now, or in the future, or
>   never.

So you can use:

- [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to chain asynchronous operations
- [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) if you need to wait for the result of multiple asynchronous operations before proceeding, eg.

```
$.when($.ajax('/page1.php'), $.ajax('/page2.php')).done(function(a1, a2){
    // eg. Perform another $.ajax call based on the results a1 and a2
});
```

Simple example, where a list of users is loaded first, then the posts of each user are retrieved based on the user id:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
   
// Returns 10 users
function getUsers() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: root + '/users',
    method: 'GET'
  });
}

// Returns posts based on user id
function getUserPosts(userId) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts?userId=' + userId,
    method: 'GET'
  });
}

// Once users list is retrieved, we can fetch posts for each users 
getUsers().then(function(users) {
  console.log('Users retrieved from API:', users);
  $.each(users, function(i, user) {
    getUserPosts(user.id).then(function(posts) {
      console.log('Posts fetched for user', user.name, posts);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Promises are definitely the way to go, but jQuery's implementation [has serious and inherent problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23744774/2014893) (prior to jQuery 3.0, at least.) Very easy to be caught out, especially for those new to Promises.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RobertK.Bell, I updated the code snippet to use at least latest jQuery version. I totally agree that using native Promise is the way to go when possible, but as OP was using jQuery I provided a jQuery oriented answer. But of course, all of this can be achieved with ES6 fetch and Promises.

Comment: Is this the best practice when calling different parts of a system API to be used/combined across the script? I was trying to use var orderDetails =""; $.ajax({url:/api/orders, type:GET, success: function (orders) { orderDetails = orders;} }); then I could use orderDetails.apidata quite everywhere but I am still not able to combine things properly would you say $.when and .then() still works better?

Comment: I thought you were asking for a way to get data from multiple async operations, possibly needing the result of previous one(s) to get another, that's why $.Deferred and $.when are suitable.
If you want a way to re-use the fetched data from the API, you can store them in memory in an object or use a persistent caching mecanism (sessionStorage, localStorage etc.). 
There is no obvious answer and depends on many factors (project structure, framework etc. you use)